# Using Maven to build iOS

Tags: ios, maven

I am having issues with getting Maven to build out my iOS app. My plug in is set up like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sap.prd.mobile.ios.mios</groupId>
    <artifactId>xcode-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <settings>
            <ARCHS>armv7 armv7s</ARCHS>
            <ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH>NO</ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH>
        </settings>
        <sdks> 
            <sdk>iphonesimulator</sdk> 
        </sdks>
        <configurations>
            <configuration>Debug</configuration> 
        </configurations>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
The build has not been performed for default configuration 'Release' and default sdk 'iphoneos'
```

even though I'm trying to exclude Release by adding only the Debug configuration.  What am I doing wrong here?  I'd like to also build release, but I am trying to exclude it for now since it is giving me issues.

I've been stuck on this for about a month, sadly. So, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a bug with version 1.14.0.  Please update to version 1.14.1 of this xcode-maven-plugin to fix this issue.